# How do I recover temp files from Dreamweaver CS5?

Tags: html, css, crash, dreamweaver

Right now I've been through one of the most frustrating moments of my life.

I've spent the whole afternoon/night making a webpage on dreamweaver, and somehow forgot to keep it saved. Then, 5 minutes ago, Dreamweaver crashed, leaving me with nothing more than the file from where I started coding this afternoon.

I was wondering if is there any way whatsoever for me to recover the files I was working on (a .html and .css files). Maybe on a Temp folder? I will be eternally grateful if you show me how to do that.

Comment: did you restarted computer???

Comment: the Dreamweaver restarted itself after crashing, but the computer hasn't been restarted still